# Android и оперативная память

Tags: android, bitmap, memory

Представим гипотетическую ситуацию.
Есть `ImageView`, в нее загружаем `Bitmap`.

Поворачиваем экран, активити в котором это все лежит пересоздается.
`Memory Monitor` показывает что при создании новой активити все заново загружается в оперативку. Если много раз переворачивать экран, то память забивается и приложение вылетает.

В чем вопрос, как сделать чтобы при пересоздании активити память освобождалась, ибо сборщик мусора не справляется.

Про сжатие `Bitmap` знаю, но в приложении важно хорошее качество и это борьба с следствием, а не причиной.

`Bitmap.recycle` тоже не эффективно.

`LargeHeap="true"` тоже борется с симптомами, а не болезнью.

Comment: "то память забивается и приложение вылетает"...ну если она забивается значит `течет` ваше приложение, в обратном случае `gc`бы ее чистил, да, возможно с тормозами(если большие объемы), но приложение бы не вылетало.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Наткнулся на форуме на такой вариант:

```
using (var bmp = BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(rs, Resource.Drawable.teaterKat))
{
    imageKategori.SetImageBitmap (bmp);               
    bmp.Dispose ();
}
```

может тебе пригодится ...